# Automatically mount encrypted home folder on login

Tags: encryption, pam, truecrypt, home

I'm looking into encrypting my home folder with Truecrypt, and mounting it after I've logged in, which should be pretty straightforward. However, it occurred to me that it should be theoretically possible to mount it *as* I'm logging in, as long as my account password is the same as my Truecrypt password. Is there a way to get PAM to run a command on login and pass the command my password as an argument? Or is there some other way to accomplish the same effect, without me needing to provide the password multiple times?

Comment: See http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/.  I know it can pass passwords to dm-crypt+luks, not sure about Truecrypt though.

Comment: Pam_mount can pass passwords to many file or disk encryption methods supported by Linux (dm-crypt, encfs, …), but [note truecrypt](http://pam-mount.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=pam-mount/pam-mount;a=blob;f=doc/bugs.txt;hb=93395a33115df99c7d012a391486ba466823e68e#1113).

Comment: you could do something like this: http://outlyer.net/howtos-linux/pam_mount-encfs/ note: I'm not saying use encfs.  It's a way to get a script to be run by pam_mount

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial for PAM and truecrypt combination: http://blog.littleimpact.de/index.php/2008/08/19/automatic-encryption-of-home-directories-using-truecrypt-60a/